# Observable.toFlowable() fails with out of memory error in rxjava2

Tags: rx-java2

Why does this fails with out of memory error

```
Observable.fromIterable(IntStream.range(1, 100000).boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                    .delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .reduce((x, y) -> x + y)
                    .blockingGet();
```

but this does not?

```
Flowable.fromIterable(  IntStream.range(1, 100).boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList()) )
                .delay( 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .reduce( (x, y) -> x+y )
                .blockingGet();
```

I assumed that once we convert Observable.toFlowable(...) both of them should work in the same way?

To test this i set -Xmx20m in Vm options

Comment: You have 1000x more items in the first example.

Comment: Otherwise, you have more buffers and thus more item retention. With `toFlowable` you have 100k in the `fromIterable`, 100k in the `toFlowable` buffer and 100k in `delay`. Without it, you have 100k in `fromIterable` and 100k in `delay`.